# Getting ABCD sequence of exercises with "esami" package

Tags: random, esami

I am using exami package for a random choice of exercises in a list. I have a list of 4 different exercises A, B, C, D and the random choice can be something like

D-B-C-B-A-C-B-A-D-A-D-B

now I see that every couple of adjacent tests has always different exercises which is good but I would like to have something more: I want that every adjacent 4 tests have different exercises, so I would like a sequence like

A-B-C-D-A-B-C-D

or

A-C-D-B-A-C-D-B.

Is there a way to get this additional constraint or to force a specific choice?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I fully understand your question. Are you trying to "fix" somehow the rotation of exercises, so that the first version has the same exercises of the fifth, and so on? Or is something else?

Comment: My focus is on a single exercise of a test. If this exercise is picked from a list of 4 possible choices I want that the choice for the version n. x to be equal to the choice for the version x+4

Comment: The `esami` package does not allow a behaviour like the one you want. There is an option `\noshuffle` that allows to stop the rotation of exercises inside a version of a test, but nothing that produces the behaviour you want. If you want, you can send your files by e-mail and we will try to work on them.